# if statement for String in setters

Tags: java, setter

how do i can put if statement for string length in setters 
like if i want the user to inter course name but in the  setter i want to put if statement like exactly 4 chars long

```
if ( (??????) == 4 )
  n= name ; 
else  
  System.out.println("it should be 4 char long") ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using `Java`.
This is kind of logic you can implement in your solution:

```
public void setCourseName(String name){
  if(name == null || name.length() != 4){
    //Do something which will handle the incorrect data
    System.out.println("Incorrect value!");
  }else{
    System.out.println("Correct value!");
  }
}
```

Comment: i did try it but it didn't work         >>                                                                                                   public void setName (String s ) {
     if(name == null || name.length() != 4)
      System.out.println("Course name should be 4 long char");
     else 
      name = s ;
    }

Comment: What do you mean by it didn't work, what is your expected behaviour?